# Pure Javascript - Perform callback in form submit eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to attach an event listener to the form submission. The function I want to call is 'callback'.
Here is the thing: I don't understand how I am supposed to pass arguments to the function (should it be the 'event' argument?)

```
if(form.addEventListener){
    form.addEventListener('submit', interrupt, false);  
}else if(form.attachEvent){
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', interrupt);            
} 

function interrupt(event){
    //deal with form submission here
}

//OR  (???)

interrupt = function(event){
    //deal with form submission here
}
```

I know this question might seem basic but I really don't understand how it should work...

Comment: You don't have to call the event listener. The browser does it for you, with `event` as the parameter.

Comment: Go with the first `function interrupt(event){` and read about [Function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Answer (score 0):

Run this example and look for console of browser. When bind dynamic event, the event is injected. For this, the function call must receive the first parameter

```js
var input = document.getElementById('ipTest');

if(input.addEventListener){
    input.addEventListener('click', interrupt, false);  
}else if(input.attachEvent){
    input.attachEvent('onclick', interrupt);            
} 

function interrupt(event){
    console.log("Event: " + event);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Test" id="ipTest"/>
```